# react material-ui on IE 11

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on a react site that makes use of Material-ui components. I couldn't get the app to render in IE without using pollyfil. I've since added polyfil and the components are rendering correctly. HOWEVER... I have a TextField that works perfectly fine in chrome and it's rendering in IE. Below is how it's configured.

```
          <TextField
            tabIndex="0"
            required
            variant="outlined"
            id="outLined-StreetNumber"
            key="streetNumber"
            error={avt.streetNumberError}
            helperText={
              avt.streetNumberError ? translation("address.StreetNumberError") : ""
            }
            label={translation("address.StreetNumber")}
            value={avt.StreetNumber}
            onChange={(event) => {
              avt.setStreetNumber(event.target.value);
            }}
            onBlur={(event) => {
              validateSteetNumber(event);
            }}
          />
```

The problem is that when using IE, I can't type into the textfield. The cursor is there but I type and no text shows.

If I added the below, then the text shows when I type. Which is great but the font size is large.

inputProps={{style: {fontSize: 21}}} // font size of input text

So if I make this font size anything less than 21, you're unable to enter any text again.

Thoughts?

EDIT:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Paper, TextField, Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useTranslation, getLanguage } from "react-multi-lang";
import { AvtContext } from "../../avtContext";

export default function ServiceAddress() {
  const avt = useContext(AvtContext);
  let language = getLanguage();
  let path = language + ".json";
  const translation = useTranslation(path);

  return (
    <Paper>
      <Grid>
        <TextField
          label="This works"
          inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 40 } }}
        />

        <TextField
          label="This doesn't work"
          inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 15 } }}
        />

        <TextField
          tabIndex="0"
          required
          variant="outlined"
          id="outLined-StreetNumber"
          key="streetNumber"
          error={avt.streetNumberError}
          helperText={
            avt.streetNumberError
              ? translation("address.StreetNumberError")
              : ""
          }
          label={translation("address.StreetNumber")}
          value={avt.StreetNumber}
          onChange={(event) => {
            avt.setStreetNumber(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "avt-front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler": "^2.7.5",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui": "^2.7.5",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.12.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "devextreme": "^20.2.4",
    "devextreme-react": "20.2.3",
    "edit-json-file": "^1.6.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.0",
    "load-json-file": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-api": "^1.0.5",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-country-region-selector-material-ui": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-fetch-hook": "^1.8.5",
    "react-material-ui-form-validator": "^2.1.1",
    "react-multi-lang": "^2.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.1",
    "write-json-file": "^4.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "react-hooks"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "react-hooks/rules-of-hooks": "error",
      "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "devextreme-themebuilder": "^20.2.4",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.3",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.7.0"
  },
  "homepage": "./"
}
```

Comment: Maybe helpful https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14420 have a look

Comment: Material-UI v4 works completely fine with IE 11. It would be helpful if you provided the full code necessary to reproduce the issue. It looks like you are using a couple additional libraries (other than Material-UI) with this Textfield (whatever libraries `avt` and `translation` are interacting with). I know for sure that an outlined TextField by itself works just fine in IE 11. It would help to know what version of Material-UI you are using.

Comment: IE11 is a pain to develop for. I would recommend  not worrying about it anymore since microsoft themselves are discontinuing it soon

Comment: @RyanCogswell I see what you mean, I stripped everything and just had the material ui textfield in my index.js and like you said, it works. I'll start adding everything back and see where it goes wrong. Thank you for the tip!!

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thank you! I found the issue. There some some CSS in the App.css for inputs that must have been causing some issues. The TextFields are now working as expected. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue with creating my app. Here is the quick answer. Nothing works with IE(any version). Unless this is for your job, it's best to ignore IE and never fix for it. Its EOL is coming up very soon anyways, June 15, 2022, and even Microsoft is asking people to stop using IE in favor of Edge, which is just their version of Chrome.

- I recently had to convince my supervisor to stop having us code for IE.

I ended up mocking up my own css to get anything to work on IE. I was able to do so using the makeStyles and createStyles hooks provided with MUI.

My code literally had 2 different files, one for IE and one for everything else.

It's easier to use basic DOM elements instead of MUIs beautiful, modified elements and style it yourself. It will save you a lot of headache if you do need to develop for IE.

Comment: Material-UI v4 works perfectly fine in IE 11.

Comment: Yeah, but there's still no point in developing for IE if you don't have too.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've added the code and my package.json.